# spring amqp log4j2 logger thread dies silently

Tags: java, logging, rabbitmq, log4j2, spring-amqp

**EDIT**

The problem was actually in the existing app and not in the logging sytsem.
If anyone is looking for an example the code i posted here is working.

**Original**

I have to integrate an existing java8 application into a productive environment. One requirement is to append all error logs to an existing (and productively working) RabbitMQ.The application uses slf4j and log4j2 for logging.

To append the messages to RabbitMQ I used the org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit, the messages are published in the correct exchange & queue however the thread that logged the message dies silently and the whole java process wont exit afterwards.

I have created a somewhat minimal example to recreate the issue.

build.gradle

```
group 'logtest'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
ext {
    slf4jVersion = '1.7.25'
}
configurations.all {
    exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
}
dependencies {
    compile("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:$slf4jVersion")
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version: '2.9.1'
    compile group: 'com.lmax', name: 'disruptor', version: '3.3.4'

    compile('org.springframework.amqp:spring-amqp:2.0.0.RELEASE') {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-core'
    }
    compile 'org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:2.0.0.RELEASE'
}

task buildLogTest(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'LogTest',
                'Implementation-Version': 1.0,
                'Main-Class': 'LogTest'
    }
    baseName = 'LogTest'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

LogTest.java

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class LogTest {
    public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
        Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogTest.class);

        Thread t = new Thread(()->{
            log.trace("trace");
            log.debug("debug");
            log.info("info");
            log.warn("warn");
            log.error("error");
            log.trace("trace");
        });

        t.setName("bg_logger");
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();

        Thread.sleep(1000 * 60);
    }
}
```

log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile">
        <FileName>log_file.log</FileName>
        <FilePattern>log/time-based-logs/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.zip</FilePattern>
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="2" modulate="true" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
    </RollingFile>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p %C{2} - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
    <RabbitMQ name="rabbitmq"
              addresses="host.local:5672"
              user="panoptesLogAgent"
              password="password"
              virtualHost="lab"
              exchange="LogExchange"
              applicationId="panoptesAutoSegmentation"
              routingKeyPattern="Critical"
              contentType="text/plain"
              contentEncoding="UTF-8"
              generateId="false"
              deliveryMode="NON_PERSISTENT"
              exchangeType="direct"
              charset="UTF-8"
              senderPoolSize="1" maxSenderRetries="1">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
    </RabbitMQ>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <AsyncLogger name="asyncRabbitMQ" level="trace" includeLocation="true">
        <AppenderRef ref="rabbitmq"/>
    </AsyncLogger>
    <Root level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="rabbitmq" level="ERROR"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" level="DEBUG"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" level="INFO"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Example Output of the STDOUT logger:

```
2017-10-18 16:49:16,986 main DEBUG Initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\Users\marek.arnold\IdeaProjects\logtest\build\resources\main\log4j2.xml]
2017-10-18 16:49:16,986 main DEBUG Installed 1 script engine
2017-10-18 16:49:17,376 main DEBUG Oracle Nashorn version: 1.8.0_131, language: ECMAScript, threading: Not Thread Safe, compile: true, names: [nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript], factory class: jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory
2017-10-18 16:49:17,376 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Core' found 116 plugins
2017-10-18 16:49:17,376 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
2017-10-18 16:49:17,376 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Lookup' found 13 plugins
2017-10-18 16:49:17,376 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
2017-10-18 16:49:17,392 main DEBUG PluginManager 'TypeConverter' found 26 plugins
2017-10-18 16:49:17,408 main DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C (%F:%L) - %m%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(C:\Users\marek.arnold\IdeaProjects\logtest\build\resources\main\log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", disableAnsi="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2017-10-18 16:49:17,408 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 42 plugins
2017-10-18 16:49:17,423 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy].
2017-10-18 16:49:17,439 main DEBUG TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy$Builder(interval="2", modulate="true", maxRandomDelay="null")
2017-10-18 16:49:17,439 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=Policies, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CompositeTriggeringPolicy].
2017-10-18 16:49:17,439 main DEBUG createPolicy(={TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=2, modulate=true)})
2017-10-18 16:49:17,439 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=DefaultRolloverStrategy, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.DefaultRolloverStrategy].
2017-10-18 16:49:17,439 main DEBUG DefaultRolloverStrategy$Builder(max="5", min="null", fileIndex="null", compressionLevel="null", ={}, stopCustomActionsOnError="null", tempCompressedFilePattern="null", Configuration(C:\Users\marek.arnold\IdeaProjects\logtest\build\resources\main\log4j2.xml))
2017-10-18 16:49:17,439 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender].
2017-10-18 16:49:17,454 main DEBUG RollingFileAppender$Builder(fileName="panoptes.log", filePattern="log/time-based-logs/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.zip", append="null", locking="null", Policies(CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=2, modulate=true)])), DefaultRolloverStrategy(DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=5, useMax=true)), advertise="null", advertiseUri="null", createOnDemand="null", filePermissions="null", fileOwner="null", fileGroup="null", bufferedIo="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", ignoreExceptions="null", PatternLayout(%d %-5p [%t] %C (%F:%L) - %m%n), name="RollingFile", Configuration(C:\Users\marek.arnold\IdeaProjects\logtest\build\resources\main\log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2017-10-18 16:49:17,454 main DEBUG Starting RollingFileManager panoptes.log
2017-10-18 16:49:17,470 main DEBUG PluginManager 'FileConverter' found 2 plugins
2017-10-18 16:49:17,470 main DEBUG Setting prev file time to 2017-10-18T16:49:17.454+0200
2017-10-18 16:49:17,470 main DEBUG Initializing triggering policy CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=2, modulate=true)])
2017-10-18 16:49:17,470 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
2017-10-18 16:49:17,470 main DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d %-5p %C{2} - %m%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(C:\Users\marek.arnold\IdeaProjects\logtest\build\resources\main\log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", disableAnsi="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2017-10-18 16:49:17,470 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender].
2017-10-18 16:49:17,470 main DEBUG ConsoleAppender$Builder(target="SYSTEM_OUT", follow="null", direct="null", bufferedIo="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", ignoreExceptions="null", PatternLayout(%d %-5p %C{2} - %m%n), name="STDOUT", Configuration(C:\Users\marek.arnold\IdeaProjects\logtest\build\resources\main\log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2017-10-18 16:49:17,470 main DEBUG Jansi is not installed, cannot find org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
2017-10-18 16:49:17,470 main DEBUG Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false
2017-10-18 16:49:17,470 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
2017-10-18 16:49:17,470 main DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C (%F:%L) - %m%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(C:\Users\marek.arnold\IdeaProjects\logtest\build\resources\main\log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", disableAnsi="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2017-10-18 16:49:17,470 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.log4j2.AmqpAppender].
2017-10-18 16:49:17,486 main DEBUG createAppender(Configuration(C:\Users\marek.arnold\IdeaProjects\logtest\build\resources\main\log4j2.xml), name="rabbitmq", PatternLayout(%d %-5p [%t] %C (%F:%L) - %m%n), Filter=null, ignoreExceptions="false", uri="null", host="null", port="null", addresses="host.local:5672", user="panoptesLogAgent", password="password", virtualHost="lab", useSsl="false", sslAlgorithm="null", sslPropertiesLocation="null", keyStore="null", keyStorePassphrase="null", keyStoreType="null", trustStore="null", trustStorePassphrase="null", trustStoreType="null", senderPoolSize="1", maxSenderRetries="1", applicationId="panoptesAutoSegmentation", routingKeyPattern="Critical", generateId="false", deliveryMode="NON_PERSISTENT", exchange="LogExchange", exchangeType="direct", declareExchange="false", durable="false", autoDelete="false", contentType="text/plain", contentEncoding="UTF-8", clientConnectionProperties="null", async="false", charset="UTF-8")
2017-10-18 16:49:17,486 main DEBUG Starting AmqpManager rabbitmq
2017-10-18 16:49:17,658 main DEBUG Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
2017-10-18 16:49:17,658 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 42 plugins
2017-10-18 16:49:17,658 main DEBUG Jansi is not installed, cannot find org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
2017-10-18 16:49:17,658 main DEBUG Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-2
2017-10-18 16:49:17,704 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin].
2017-10-18 16:49:17,704 main DEBUG createAppenders(={RollingFile, STDOUT, rabbitmq})
2017-10-18 16:49:17,704 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2017-10-18 16:49:17,704 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="rabbitmq", level="null", Filter=null)
2017-10-18 16:49:17,704 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=asyncLogger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerConfig].
2017-10-18 16:49:17,704 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="null", level="trace", name="asyncRabbitMQ", includeLocation="true", ={rabbitmq}, ={}, Configuration(C:\Users\marek.arnold\IdeaProjects\logtest\build\resources\main\log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2017-10-18 16:49:17,704 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2017-10-18 16:49:17,704 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="rabbitmq", level="ERROR", Filter=null)
2017-10-18 16:49:17,704 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2017-10-18 16:49:17,704 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="RollingFile", level="DEBUG", Filter=null)
2017-10-18 16:49:17,720 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2017-10-18 16:49:17,720 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="STDOUT", level="INFO", Filter=null)
2017-10-18 16:49:17,720 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger].
2017-10-18 16:49:17,720 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="null", level="TRACE", includeLocation="null", ={rabbitmq, RollingFile, STDOUT}, ={}, Configuration(C:\Users\marek.arnold\IdeaProjects\logtest\build\resources\main\log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2017-10-18 16:49:17,720 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin].
2017-10-18 16:49:17,720 main DEBUG createLoggers(={asyncRabbitMQ, root})
2017-10-18 16:49:17,720 main DEBUG Configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\Users\marek.arnold\IdeaProjects\logtest\build\resources\main\log4j2.xml] initialized
2017-10-18 16:49:17,720 main DEBUG Starting configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\Users\marek.arnold\IdeaProjects\logtest\build\resources\main\log4j2.xml]
2017-10-18 16:49:17,767 main DEBUG Starting AsyncLoggerConfig disruptor for this configuration with ringbufferSize=4096, waitStrategy=TimeoutBlockingWaitStrategy, exceptionHandler=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerConfigDefaultExceptionHandler@f5f7f...
2017-10-18 16:49:17,767 main DEBUG Started configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\Users\marek.arnold\IdeaProjects\logtest\build\resources\main\log4j2.xml] OK.
2017-10-18 16:49:17,767 main DEBUG Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1
2017-10-18 16:49:17,767 main DEBUG Shut down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1, all resources released: true
2017-10-18 16:49:17,767 main DEBUG Appender DefaultConsole-1 stopped with status true
2017-10-18 16:49:17,767 main DEBUG Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@2e1f26 OK
2017-10-18 16:49:17,829 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=b4aac2
2017-10-18 16:49:17,829 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=b4aac2,component=StatusLogger
2017-10-18 16:49:17,829 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=b4aac2,component=ContextSelector
2017-10-18 16:49:17,829 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=
2017-10-18 16:49:17,829 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=asyncRabbitMQ
2017-10-18 16:49:17,829 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=asyncRabbitMQ,subtype=RingBuffer
2017-10-18 16:49:17,829 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=b4aac2,component=Appenders,name=STDOUT
2017-10-18 16:49:17,829 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=b4aac2,component=Appenders,name=rabbitmq
2017-10-18 16:49:17,829 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=b4aac2,component=Appenders,name=RollingFile
2017-10-18 16:49:17,829 main DEBUG Reconfiguration complete for context[name=b4aac2] at URI C:\Users\marek.arnold\IdeaProjects\logtest\build\resources\main\log4j2.xml (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@156d4d4) with optional ClassLoader: null
2017-10-18 16:49:17,829 main DEBUG Shutdown hook enabled. Registering a new one.
2017-10-18 16:49:17,829 main DEBUG LoggerContext[name=b4aac2, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@156d4d4] started OK.
2017-10-18 16:49:17,845 INFO  LogTest - info
2017-10-18 16:49:17,845 WARN  LogTest - warn
Okt 18, 2017 4:49:17 PM org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory createBareConnection
INFORMATION: Created new connection: SpringAMQP#131f24d:0/SimpleConnection@2fd3f6 [delegate=amqp://panoptesLogAgent@172.16.13.186:5672/lab, localPort= 52013]
2017-10-18 16:49:17,845 ERROR LogTest - error
```

The process does not exit on its own. If the logging is done in the main thread instead of a seperate thread the main thread dies silently (not visible in threaddump) after sending the log message to the RabbitMQ. For both options RabbitMQ receives the correct message.

Thank you in advance for any help! If you need more information I am happy to provide it.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "dies silently" if the thread exits main, then of course it terminates. The JVM is probably staying up because of the RabbitMQ connection; that will shut down if/when the logging system is stopped. You can always call `System.exit(0)`.

Comment: Thank you for you quick reply, it was my bad, i found the error. There was an unrelated bug with the legacy app and i mistakenly pinned it down to the logging system.